# Why can't I type commands in terminal while an application is running?

Tags: command-line

I'm new to Ubuntu and I've been experimenting with commands in the terminal. I opened chrome by typing "google-chrome" and a bunch of code appeared in the terminal. I then tried to type more commands in the terminal and now it doesn't register as commands. What's happening?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4OqM.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The `google-chrome` process is busy running from that terminal window.

You'll notice that if you close that window, that Chrome will also terminate.

If your current terminal window is busy, you can open another terminal window to run other commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the command google-chrome in the background by typing & at the end of the command ie "google-chrome &". This will give you the job number allotted to this command and free the shell for other commands. You can find out the number of jobs running by typing "jobs" at the terminal.
The job can be brought back to the foreground by typing "fg %1" for job number 1.

Answer (score 0):

The program runs in the shell that you opened it from. If you press ctrl+c the program will terminate and close and you will have a command line again. You can also open a new shell (or tab in a terminal) to keep using other commands.

edit: you can also run a program in the background by appending & to the end of the command, keeping the shell available for other commands.

Example: firefox &